# Android: CountdownTimer in ListView || Performance

Tags: android, listview, countdowntimer

I'm developing at the moment a ListView, which contains multiple CountdownTimers.
I solved that, with starting the CountdownTimer directly in my BaseAdapter (getView()).
With my solution it's working, but i think this is very wasteful for resources!?

What do you think, is it good or is there a better solution?

My second question refers to the lifecicle. 
When I'm closing my App or switching Activty, or whatever I have to cancle my Task, but how can i access it from my Fragment/Activity ?

Here is my Adapter:

```
public class GamesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<GamesData> data;
private Date d1 = null;
private Date d2 = null;

public GamesAdapter(Context context, List<GamesData> data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_games, null);

        GamesData gamesData = data.get(position);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(gamesData.getName());

        final TextView time = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.time);

        try {
            d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy HH:mm:ss").parse(gamesData
                    .getCurrentDateandTime());
            d2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy HH:mm:ss").parse(gamesData
                    .getDate());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
        DateCountDownTimer mTimer = new DateCountDownTimer(diff, 1000, time);

        **// Here I'm starting the Timer !!**
        mTimer.start();

    }

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Looking forward for helpful/informative answers and thanks in advance.

Best regards Jul

Comment: I don't understand how this code should work. What does your ListView do with CountDownTimer-instances if you scroll the ListView? In your code, you don't handle the case for scrolling with (convertView != null) for recycled ListView-views. Does your ListAdapter have so few items to not fill the ListView-screen fully so that this case never happens?

Comment: you're right, I forgot to handle this case. 
But my code works well, every listItem is counting down it's own timer, even if I'm counting.